# Failed to send message

Tags: php

I have a problem on sending message to email list(text file).

Code:

```
<?php
$to="emails.txt";
$subject="Hey";
$txt="Hello...";
mail($to,$subject,$txt);
?>
```

i do not have any syntax errors.... 
the msg is not sent to the emails list , that is the proplem here

Please advice and Thanks

Comment: if you have some txt file where every email address in new line, you can make this:
`$file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
$subject="Hey";
$txt="Hello...";
while(!feof($file)){
    $to = fgets($file);
    mail($to,$subject,$txt);
}
fclose($file);`

Comment: @Samuel Loog , Tnx alot worked [:

Answer (score 0):

if you have some txt file where every email address in new line, you can make this:

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
$subject="Hey";
$txt="Hello...";
while(!feof($file)){
    $to = fgets($file);
    mail($to,$subject,$txt);
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$to` variable in your code contains the text only from the file name, but not the details of it. To be successful, you need to get data from a file and run them by sending a letter to each.

function `file()` reads a file into an array, and `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` key removes the line break charset value of each row. Thus it is possible to obtain an array of emails.

```
$arrayTo = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$subject="Hey";
$txt="Hello...";
foreach($arrayTo as $to){
    mail($to,$subject,$txt);
}
```